# Can't include header in cpp file

Tags: c++, eclipse, makefile, gnu-make

I wish to include this in my cpp file:

```
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
```

For my Makefile Project I have selected Properties>Path and Symbols>GNU C++>Include Directories> 
and added:

```
/opt/local/include
```

But I get this error when I try to build:

```
**** Build of configuration Default for project Main ****

make all 
g++ -O2 -g -Wall  -fmessage-length=0   -c -o Main.o Main.cpp
Main.cpp:107:35: error: boost/lambda/lambda.hpp: No such file or directory
```

What might the problem be?

The file /opt/local/include/boost/lambda/lambda.hpp exists.

This is my makefile:

```
CXXFLAGS =  -O2 -g -Wall  -fmessage-length=0

SRCS =      Main.cpp 
OBJS =      Main.o 
LIBS =      -framework CoreMIDI -framework CoreAudio -framework CoreFoundation -framework CoreServices

TARGET =    Main 

$(TARGET):  $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) -Wall -D__MACOSX_CORE__ -o $(TARGET) $(SRCS) $(LIBS)

all:    $(TARGET)

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(TARGET)
```

Comment: Is /opt/local/include in your lib path? I don't know if it is by default on Linux.

Comment: The invocation line seems to be missing `-I /opt/local/include`. It could be that there's an environment variable set somewhere, but that's unlikely. Check your configuration settings again.

Comment: I've added CXXFLGAS += -I/opt/local/include to the makefile but still no luck. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @KerrekSB Better: `-isystem`. This prevents a heap of irrelevant warnings and allows you to compile with `-Werror` set.

Comment: Notice the misspelling: `CXXFLGAS` should be `CXXFLAGS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should work.

```
CXXFLAGS =  -O2 -g -Wall  -fmessage-length=0

SRCS =      Main.cpp 
OBJS =      Main.o 
LIBS =      -framework CoreMIDI -framework CoreAudio -framework CoreFoundation -    framework CoreServices
INCL_DIR = /opt/local/include
TARGET =    Main 

$(TARGET):  $(OBJS)
$(CXX) -Wall -D__MACOSX_CORE__ -o $(TARGET) $(SRCS) $(LIBS) -I $(INCL_DIR)

all:    $(TARGET)

clean:
rm -f $(OBJS) $(TARGET)
```